# Could not find method create() for arguments - Crashlytics issue

Tags: android, crashlytics

```
Could not find method create() for arguments [crashlyticsStoreDeobsDebug, class com.crashlytics.tools.gradle.tasks.StoreMappingFileTask, com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildArtifactsHolder$FinalBuildableArtifact@2ac9ac29] on task set of type org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer.
```

Project was in working state but since today build is failing with above error.

Android Studio 3.2 Preview.

Comment: Please attach your gradle and any other file concerning the issue.

Comment: Build get successful if I comment "apply plugin: 'io.fabric'" line but if I uncomment it as before build fails with a given error.

Comment: Yesterday, 3.2 is the stable version i guess.

Answer (score 66):

## Update: Check [Mike's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52503456) first!

## Old answer:

It looks like Fabric released a new version thats breaks the build for some apps.

If you have the line `io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+` (which is recommended by Fabric, but not ideal) you will automatically use the new version.

In the meantime you can replace `1.+` with the latest "stable" version which is 1.25.4. `io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4`

Comment: Small update: the latest version is 1.26.0. But that doesn't work. Setting the version to 1.25.4 does the trick

Comment: When you are using 1.+ version which  basically use latest version 1.26.0 and the bug occurred. So, make sure you are using 1.25.4 to resolve the issue

Comment: Solved but this is not the best solution. Waiting fabric fix this.

Comment: there was a problem with version 1.26, with version 1.25.4 all ok

Comment: It is generally bad practice to use `+` in version numbers. The fact that Fabric recommends this for their plugin has always irked me. Instead, I manually check when there are new versions using this: https://maven.fabric.io/public/io/fabric/tools/gradle/maven-metadata.xml

Answer (score 33):

Mike from Fabric here. If you're using version `3.2` of the Android Studio Gradle plugin, upgrading to `4.10` of Gradle **and** `1.26.0` of the Fabric Gradle plugin will address this issue.

If you use a version of AS Gradle less then `3.2`, you won't encounter the issue, but also won't be getting the benefits of the latest release. You will hit this issue if you've updated to `3.2` of AS Gradle **and** `1.26.0` of Fabric's Gradle plugin, **but** are using a version of Gradle lower than `4.10` of Gradle.

Comment: confirmed - this works also. The resulting Gradle Sync take 4 mins 25sec (fast internet and working off an SSD)

Comment: Hi, @Mike for my case 1.25.4 worked. But 1.26.0 is still failing.

Comment: Hey Mohammad, did you update to 1.26.0 of Fabric, 3.2 of AS Gradle and 4.10 of Gradle itself?

Comment: confirmed; updating Gradle to `4.10.2` fixes issues with fabric `1.26.0`

Comment: Can't you just make it working in old versions of gradle too?

Comment: Version 1.26.1 has a backward compatible fix.

Answer (score 12):

when you update with **android studio 3.2** and using **fabric gradle** version **1.+** then you have to change fabric gradle version **1.+** to **1.25.4** in **biuld.gradle(project)** file

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    //classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'     // old version
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'   // new version
}
}
```

**Note:** Although the fabric gradle latest version is **1.26.0** but it's not **stable** version.**stable** version is **1.25.4**. its work fine.

Answer (score 10):

Update

```
classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
```

To

```
classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.26.1'
```

https://docs.fabric.io/android/changelog.html#september-27-2018

Version `1.26.0` was the problem

Answer (score 6):

You only need to update Gradle version (in Gradle-Wrapper.properties). for ex:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.2-all.zip
```

Answer (score 3):

Following Mike's answer the file you need to change is in:

`project\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties`

The latest version is `4.10.2`.

Answer (score 2):

For me, the problem appeared when I updated to AS 3.2-RC02 which requires the Android plugin `3.2.0-rc02`.

So I had to roll back to AS 3.1.4 which is the current stable version so I could downgrade my version of the Android plugin. I am using Android plugin `3.2.0-rc01`

I also had to downgrade the fabric plugin to `1.24.4`

Answer (score 0):

Now seeing this with Gradle 5.1.1

Crashlytics version: 2.9.3

Gradle Tools version: 1.21.7

> ERROR: Could not find method leftShift() for arguments [com.crashlytics.tools.gradle.tasks.FabricTaskBuilder$_pluginGenerateResources_closure4@28a32300] on task ':App:fabricGenerateResourcesDebug' of type org.gradle.api.DefaultTask.