# Could not find method create() for arguments

Tags: java, android, crashlytics

I have update android studio and after sync project i got this error when build project.so please anyone help me to solve this issue.

```
Could not find method create() for arguments [crashlyticsStoreDeobsRelease, class com.crashlytics.tools.gradle.tasks.StoreMappingFileTask, com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildArtifactsHolder$FinalBuildableArtifact@18a12395] on task set of type org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer.
```

Comment: You are probably using a fairly old version of Gradle. I'd recommend upgrading. The add method on the TaskContainer was deprecated. My plugin uses the replacement method create which your Gradle version doesn't have yet. This version of the plugin is not backward compatible anymore.

Comment: Hi, I Have the same issue I Had updated Android Studio and Gradle and I have this error.

Comment: I am having the same issue.

Comment: >Follow the solution - https://stackoverflow.com/a/52510507/5788247

Comment: @Shomu yes this is the correct solution for this issue.