# after updating to Android Studio 3.2 Preview - project showing error Could not find method create()

Tags: android, crashlytics-android

error is 
**Could not find method create() for arguments [crashlyticsStoreDeobsDevRelease, class com.crashlytics.tools.gradle.tasks.StoreMappingFileTask, com.android.build.gradle.internal.scope.BuildArtifactsHolder$FinalBuildableArtifact@6eebf4be] on task set of type org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer.**

Comment: is this a question?

Comment: this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52474472/could-not-find-method-create-for-arguments-crashlytics-issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not find method create() for arguments - Crashlytics issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52474472/could-not-find-method-create-for-arguments-crashlytics-issue)

Answer (score 0):

Update the gradle version it will fix.
Also check this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52474472/could-not-find-method-create-for-arguments-crashlytics-issue) it is the exact same question.

Comment: Did you look at the link ?

Comment: yes before posting a question, I checked that solutions but still having the problem